# Reduce timeout value for "A start job is running for dev-disk-by" linux

Tags: linux, fstab, timeout, udev

My /etc/fstab *intentionally* has quite a few entries that point to (labelled) partitions and filesystems that may not be present at boot time (think: hotpluggable SATA backup disks).

These entries cause trouble during boot because I get trapped for 1min30sec (90sec) while some boot process waits for these disks or partitions to appear. The wait is accompanied by the well-known message "A start job is running for dev-disk-by" and a countup to 1m30sec.

Question: I would like to CHANGE the timeout value from 90sec to, say 10sec, so that boot and shutdown will go faster. How do I do that?

Status: I have looked high and low for the proper parameter to set. One thing I tried was to add some kernel parameter values to the appropriate grub.cfg line, as follows, but it had no effect.

udev.event-timeout=10 rd.udev.event-timeout=10 udev.exec-delay=10 rd.udev.exec-delay=10

This is on

Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)
Linux version 4.5.5-201.fc23.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat May 21 15:29:49 UTC 2016

Answer (score 4):

The answer, provided by user grawity and paraphrased here, is:

For each entry in /etc/fstab, decide whether the disk device is one that is not always present at boot time, and add

x-systemd.device-timeout=10s

to the mount options for that entry.

Example: The below is an fstab entry for a cold spare backup drive, which should mount when plugged in, but time out quickly if not present at boot time.

LABEL=B.3TB./home /mnt/3000gb-disk2/home ext4 defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10s 1 0

Status: tested and is working. My boot time is now down to about 20sec, whereas it used to be about 100sec or more. The halt/reboot time is also correspondingly improved.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **`nofail`** fstab option for those disks.

Alternatively, you could specify the `x-systemd.device-timeout=10s` option, but what's the point? systemd already supports hotplugging without the need for timeouts, but it adds dependencies on all filesystems (except `nofail` ones) to avoid requiring all services to list very detailed deps.

See [systemd.mount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) for documentation of both options.

Comment: My experience is that the fstab nofail option has no effect whatsoever. The "start job" still gets generated, and the timeout is in effect.  I will try adding the x-systemd.device-timeout=10s  in grub.cfg, I assume you mean this is a kernel parameter. Thanks!

Comment: I have now tested using x-systemd.device-timeout=10s, and it works. Note: It is an /etc/fstab option on a per-entry basis. It is not a kernel option. Thanks to grawity for providing the answer, I upvoted it but do not have enough reputation points yet to make it show.

Comment: That's odd – I've been successfully using `nofail` for quite a few nonexistent disks by now.

Comment: `nofail` still generates the annoying start jobs for me too. I'm using systemd 231 on Arch. (Which is weird, because iirc grawity also uses Arch)